# Accepting primitive array as OData action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, odata

I would like to pass an array of `int` to an ASP.NET OData route as a paremeter, and cannot get it to work.

I have tried the following:

```cs
[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers=[{numbers}])")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers=[{numbers}])")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers([FromODataUri] int[] numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers=[{numbers}])")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers([FromODataUri] int[] numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers([FromODataUri] IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers=[{numbers}])")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers([FromODataUri] IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    // snip
}

[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers()")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    // snip
}
```

In each and every case, I am getting the following error:

```
The path template 'IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})' on the action 'GetForNumbers' in controller 'IWantMeSomeNumbers' is not a valid OData path template. Bad Request - Error in query syntax.
```

Can anyone advise if this is even doable, and if so, what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, turns out that I am just misguided, and needed to define the `EntityType.CollectionParameter<int>` on the builder:

```cs
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
// snip
builder.EntityType<IAmAnAppropriateResponse>().Collection.Function(nameof(IWantMeSomeNumbersController.GetForNumbers))
    .ReturnsCollection<IAmAnAppropriateResponse>()
    .CollectionParameter<int>("numbers");
```

That paired with the following method signature, and all is working as required:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("IWantMeSomeNumbers/GetForNumbers(numbers={numbers})")]
public IQueryable<IAmAnAppropriateResponse> GetForNumbers([FromODataUri] int[] numbers)
{
    // snip
}
```

Comment: and how call the function ? "GetForNumbers(numbers=[1,2])"